# PHP - How to add content after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having difficulty... I'm trying to create a form which automatically create extra input like `.php` after the form is submitted.

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="add" placeholder="Write Test">
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

When user enters "Test" and press on submit, an automatically extension will be created like this:

```
Test.php
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to explain better what you want to achieve. You could say when do you want this to happen, on the browser with JS ? in the server with PHP itself? where do you need the name with the extension ? where the extension come from ? it's gonna be always .php ? edit you question please =)

Comment: My bad.

I would want to create an extension `.php` into a column to DB.

`$url = $_POST['url'];` / `INSERT INTO x VALUES("url')` and + extension .php ( If user wrote Test in the input. Make `Test.php` )

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved like this:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST["add"])) {
        $file = $_POST["add"] . ".php";
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            echo "File already exists";
        } else {
            fopen($file, "w");
        }
    }
?>
```

References:

Check if file is already there: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Create a file / directory : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Answer (score 0):

Concat a string:

```
$string = $_POST['add'];
$new_string = $string.'.php';
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Kisaragi , a fine solution.